# Whats causing this problem in ACF when running php 7.4?

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I recently updated my site to php 7.4. It's running a custom build wordpress theme using ACF Pro v 5.5.5. However, once updated i get this error:

```
Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in wp-content/plugins/advanced-custom-fields-pro/api/api-template.php on line 503
```

The snippet it refers to looks like this:

```
    acf_add_loop(array(
        'selector'  => $selector,
        'name'      => $field['name'], // line 503
        'value'     => $value,
        'field'     => $field,
        'i'         => -1,
        'post_id'   => $post_id,
        'key'       => $key
    ));
```

I have googled this for hours without really find a solution that works. Right now i don't even know how to go further. Any suggestions? Anyone had this problem? Since it refers to ACF itself i believe it could be some php stuff in 7.4 that's not compatible, but i have really no idea.

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? What does `$field`  contain? If you cannot use a debugger like XDebug, dump it using `var_dump`

Comment: Have you tried updating to the newest version of ACF (5.9.5)? I think that 5.5.5 was still compatible with 7.4, but you could update first and see if that solves the issue. You could also ask in the ACF support, since they are super responsive.

Comment: An update did the job. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by updating to the lastest ACF (5.9.5).